# Skin font for TinyMCE

Tags: css, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have used the skin editor:

http://skin.tinymce.com

to style my text editor.

However, I don't see how I can change the font type and size.

In the skin file there is a font folder and it contains:

```
icomoon.ttf
icomoon-small.ttf
icomoon.eot
icomoon-small.eot
```

etc.

On my website I style my text as follows:

```
font-family: Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;
font-size: 11px;
```

How should I do this for the skin I have created?

Comment: icomoon its icon fonts, not letters. Do you need to change font in all page elements?

Comment: @Evgeniy I want to change the font family and size in the text editor menu and menu buttons.

Comment: then you can follow answer by @Paweł S . To apply this font to controls you need add to your css following code:  button{ font-family: 'arialregular' }.

Answer (score 4):

first of all generate webfont:

```
http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator
```

you will download pack of files. U need to copy:

```
*.eot
*.woff
*.ttf
*.svg
```

to  Skin for TinyMCE css folder

in Skin for TinyMCE, there's file named:
    skin.min.css

on top of this css file you need to include font declaration

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'arialregular';
    src: url('arial-webfont.eot');
    src: url('arial-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('arial-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('arial-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('arial-webfont.svg#arialregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

you will find it in stylesheet.css, which was generated in font squirrel

then find in
    skin.min.css
font family declaration and replace it with font name generated by font squirrel, in my example it will by :

```
    font-family: 'arialregular';
```

theoretically it should work, hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

The Verdana, Geneva font family is web safe so you will not need to add files to the font folder.

The classes that handle the editors css are as follow:

```
.mce-container, .mce-container *, .mce-widget, .mce-widget *, .mce-reset {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
outline: 0;
vertical-align: top;
background: transparent;
text-decoration: none;
color: #333333;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
text-shadow: none;
float: none;
position: static;
width: auto;
height: auto;
white-space: nowrap;
cursor: inherit;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
line-height: normal;
font-weight: normal;
text-align: left;
-moz-box-sizing: content-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
box-sizing: content-box;
direction: ltr;
}
```

So to change the font family and size you will need to add this to your css file.

```
.mce-container, .mce-container *, .mce-widget, .mce-widget *, .mce-reset {
font-family: Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;
font-size: 11px;
}
```

The file that has the above code needs to be called after the Bootstrap.min.css file in the header otherwise it will be overwritten.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

> font-family: 'icomoon-small.ttf';

This will work